# SQL Server heavy load

Tags: sql-server

I am doing some project and get stuck with heavy load of SQL Server.

My product is a website and a mobile app. During use of the mobile app, users are making about 5 logs per second. So 10,000 users are making 50,000 rows per second on the database. And about 3,000 users are login to website and show logs.

But search log of website is so slow, because of generating huge logs from mobile app.

In mobile app, I saved queries to temporary value, and run queries per 5 seconds (batch). And in website, I make query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 500 FROM Logs....
```

My website is written using ASP.NET MVC 5 and uses Entity Framework to access a SQL Server 2012 database, and the DB server specs are perfect.

How can I solve this heavy load problem?

Comment: Don't use a relational database for logging unless your logging data is actually relational data. And 5 log messages per second per user is just crazy - why do you need to measure that much detail?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Dai
I need to measure much detail, we need prove for user's compliant.
If any user use mobile app, and complain about app, we need check logs and need to answer. so absolutely we need to generate logs.
You said don't use a relational database for logging, you mean noSQL?

Comment: NoSQL databases are not necessarily the correct solution. I recommend looking for "Event Sourcing databases" or "Append-only databases" which are much better suited for this problem.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to give any kind of answer to the problem. What data is there? Table structures? Queries? Query plans?

Comment: Do you need to read the logs out of an online database? If this is for user compliance, then the user doesn't need to see it right? What you could do is back up and restore your database to a different server (or a read only replica) and read out of the replica. That way you can split the workload to two servers. One for writes, one for reads

Comment: Without knowing what the app actually does and the purpose of the logs etc - I'd go with reworking the architecture to use either multiple databases and/ or servers and/or how you communicate with your servers. But there's too little information to give proper, usable, answers

Comment: My log table schema is this:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logs](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [tableid] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [datetime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [logstring] [nvarchar](3072) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
this logs is increase 50,000 rows per second.

I used this sql query for search logs.
sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime desc) as rowNum FROM Logs WHERE username=$username and datetime >= $startdate and datetime <= $enddate) sub where rowNum between $startindex AND $endindex";

Comment: Even if I understand importance of User 's complaint even then I fail to understand how there will be 5 log/second/user.How it going to happen is not clear.BTW, in nutshell wht we understand is you hv one table with million of records and your search and load both are slow in website.This problem has nothing to do with mobile APP.For that we need table struture,sample data and desire output.along with data type,PK etc.